# How to configure the cache location outside the chroot on mockbuild

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild, chroot

Using the mockbuild to generate the rpm. The rpm involves npm. Would like to utilize the npm cache that is outside the chroot so that it does gets affected by chroot cleanup. Is that possible?

Tried to create softlinks from chroot but it does not work.
Tried to use root_cache. Neither it worked.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use Mock's BindMount plugin:
  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Mock/Plugin/BindMount
to mount the cache dir inside the chroot.

Comment: The "/host/path" is the path to a directory on the host that will be the source of a bind-mount, is being deleted every time  the mock is run.

Comment: 1)  then it is bug, please report it 2) use --no-clean

Comment: it works with --no-clean option though. I'd prefer it otherwise.